# How to initialize Current User information at ICurrentUserService after login completed successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I try to keep user login information and last login date when each login. I have a ICurrentUserService interface and CurrentUserService class implement it.

```cs
public interface ICurrentUserService 
{
    long? UserId { get; }
    bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    
    public bool HasAnyPermissionInPermissionGroup(string claimGroup);
    
    public bool HasPermission(string claimName);
}

public class CurrentUserService: ICurrentUserService 
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public long? UserId 
    {
        get 
        {
            var userIdClaim = _httpContextAccessor
                .HttpContext?.User?
                .FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                
            return long
              .TryParse(userIdClaim, out var id) ? id : (long?)null;
        }
     }

    public bool IsAuthenticated => UserId != null && UserId != 0;

    public bool HasAnyPermissionInPermissionGroup(string claimGroup) 
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated) 
            return false;
        
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
            .User.Claims
            .Any(x => x.Type == CustomClaimTypes.Permission &&
                x.Value.StartsWith(claimGroup) &&
                x.Issuer == "LOCAL AUTHORITY");
    }

    public bool HasPermission(string claimName) 
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated)
          return false;
         
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
            .User.
            .Any(x => x.Type == CustomClaimTypes.Permission &&
                x.Value == claimName &&
                x.Issuer == "LOCAL AUTHORITY");
    }
}
```

---

That are working fine all entities. However, I am stuck with a scenario. I override .net identity login method like that (I also extend IdentityUser class):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) 
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager
            .PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            
        if (result.Succeeded) 
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName);
            
            if (user == null)
                return NotFound("Unable to load user for update last login.");
             
             
            user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var lastLoginResult = await _userManager
                .UpdateAsync(user);
                
           if (!lastLoginResult.Succeeded) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected error occurred setting the last login date" +
               $"({lastLoginResult.ToString()}) for user with ID '{user.Id}'.");
               
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
         
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor) 
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new 
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe
            });
        }
        
        if (result.IsLockedOut) 
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        } 
        else 
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

---

When updating LastLoginDate, I call DbContext SaveChangesAsyn method.

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
{
    foreach(var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IBaseEntity>()) 
    {
        switch (entry.State) 
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.Entity.CreateUserId = _currentUserService.UserId.Value;
                entry.Entity.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.Entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entry.Entity.UpdateUserId = _currentUserService.UserId.Value;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entry.Entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entry.Entity.UpdateUserId = _currentUserService.UserId.Value;
                entry.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                break;
        }
    }
          
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Inside method try to update user information but _currentUserService is not getting user information. So user information inside that class still null. How I can set this information.

Comment: What is the scope of the `ICurrentUserService` and of your `DBContext`?

Comment: What does you mean the scope. At DI, both of adding with AddScope.

Comment: So when I say scope, I mean the `Object Lifetime`. You can use `AddScoped`, `AddSingleton` and `AddTransient` and each one has a different object lifetime/cycle.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lifetime-and-registration-options

Comment: As I said previous comment both of them AddScoped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have on my `DBContext` to get similar information around the current user. I purposefully do not have a dependency in the DBContext to a `UserService` that had a dependency on the `DBContext` for circular reference issues.

Here is the setup

In Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient(provider =>
        {
            return provider?.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User ?? new ClaimsPrincipalService().GetCurrentPrincipal();
        });
}
```

In my DBContext

```
    public MyDbContextContext(DbContextOptions<ScorpionContext> options, IPrincipal principal)
        : base(options)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }


    public string CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var userId = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)_principal)?.Claims
                ?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == CustomClaimTypes.UserId)?.Value;
            return
                $@"{_deploymentEnvironmentService.MachineName}\{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) ? "-1" : userId)}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could I get logged in user info like that? They are using browser and project at IIS.